# stop button activity if function returns false

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a onclick button and a function to check if email is valid.
If it is not valid it will return false.

What I want is a way to stop the button action if it is false.

Is there a way, like `die();` in php to stop button action if boolean is false?

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                Boolean valid_email = isValidEmail(email);

//how can I stop the onclick if boolean is false?

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response){
                        try {
...
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt get  stop means you want it to disable it anything

Comment: @JanardhanR this buttom will request some information from server, so I want to stop it before this request if emails is not valid. not go ahead in the  onclicklistener

Comment: Can you tell me what are you doing when it is invalid,can you full activity then it will be better to understand

Comment: So make call to server only when it is valid don't do anything when it's unvalid

Answer (score 2):

You can disable button and call `return`  so the below code will not be executed

```
      @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                Boolean valid_email = isValidEmail(email);

                if(!valid_email){
                    button.setEnabled(false);  //disable button
                    return;
                }else{
                       button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it possible to have return in void method?

Comment: yes of course...you are not returning anything like return 0 for int...etc you are just returning the code execution to the calling method..

Comment: Thanks but doesn't he has to set it again to set enabled true

Comment: @JanardhanR ..thankx for the suggestion..you are right

Answer (score 1):

Try use something like control Thread.

which if isValidEmail(email) lock some functions.

I try writed code and you paste?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (!valid_email)
    return;
```

Comment: @RickJoe You cannot return a value from `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if(!isValidEmail(email))
    return;

//the rest of your code goes here...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If (validemail){
     //Add your response call here .I.e make server call here
}else{
  //Do nothing will be fine
   }
```